# How to make smooth moving using as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have loaded some images through XML and attached into dynamically created MovieClips named mc0,mc1,mc2...etc.

```
_loader.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoadingAction);
count++;
var img:Bitmap =  Bitmap(e.target.content);
img.cacheAsBitmap = true;
img.smoothing = true;
img.alpha = 0;
TweenLite.to(MovieClip(my_mc.getChildByName("mc"+count)).addChild(img),1, {alpha:1,ease:Quint.easeIn});
```

and within `ENTER_FRAME` handler

```
for (i=0; i < mc.numChildren; i++)
{   
    my_mc.getChildAt(i).x -= Math.round((mouseX-stage.stageWidth/2)*.006);              

}
```

Everthing works fine. But it is shaking so that it was not looking good.

How do I achieve smooth movement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution I've used is to round the (x,y) position to the closest integer. No matter that you've added smoothing to your bitmap and cached it, rounding could make it feel less choppy and way smoother.

Another thing you need to be careful is the dimensions of the images. Images that have an odd dimension won't be smoothed the same way as images with even dimensions. Check how to workaround this in my blog post [Flash Smoothing Issue](http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2009/07/31/flash-smoothing-issue/).

Comment: `Math.round((mouseX-stage.stageWidth/2)*.006);`  and width and height of the image and the movieClip are 334 and 400. Is it enough for a better move?

Comment: The rounding should happen on each update of the Tween movement. TweenLite should have onUpdate handler or something like that, where you can round the positions of the tweened movies.

Comment: I am sorry. Shaking is happening in the `Sprite` container not because of the images. and I have tried rounding and tweenlite... both r didn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

Since Flash has a variable frame rate (in the sense that it will drop frames), one shouldn't depend on the entering of a frame as a unit of action.  Rather, it would be wiser to calculate the elapsed time explicitly.

For instance, in the enter frame handler:

```
var currentTime:Number = (new Date()).time;
for (i=0; i < mc.numChildren; i++)
{   
    my_mc.getChildAt(i).x -= speed * (currentTime - lastTime); // speed is in px/ms
}
lastTime = currentTime;
```

where you have the variable `lastTime` declared somewhere in a persistent scope:

```
var lastTime:Number = (new Date()).time;
```

I don't know if this addresses what you are calling "shaking", but it's at least something to consider.

Comment: Probably the TweenLite has some options to switch from frame-based animations to time-based animations.